# How do I edit and reload HTML in Firebug?

Tags: firefox, firebug

This should be an easy one for someone.

After editing the HTML in Firebug, how do I reload the page (maintaining the edited HTML)? There is no reload button as shown frustratingly here, http://getfirebug.com/html, under "**Inspect, edit, reload**", which is exactly what I want to do:

[image]

Where is this button?!

Would be great if the answer had a picture. *EDIT: Using Firebug 1.9.1*

## Clarification EDIT:

What I am trying to do: I am removing bad HTML code hoping that it will not mess up JavaScript code which I am guessing that it is doing. Assuming the HTML code in question is messing up JavaScript, and then I remove the offending HTML code via Firebug, is a reload necessary to then execute the JavaScript code properly?

Comment: thats odd, from my experience with firebug all edits are dynamic(meaning live) and happen without refresh

Comment: My edits are also happening this way, but since I believe they are messing up, or influencing, JavaScript I want to reload to be sure. Perhaps what I want is what I already have and the page is merely not reacting as expected. EDIT: I clarified the problem. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what you're looking for. Here some facts:

- If you edit HTML in Firebug then changes take effect immediately without hitting some buttons. When you reload the page then these changes are gone.
- The button you posted is just right from the address bar and is the ordinary reload button from Firefox. Nothing from Firebug. Firebug just says when you reload the page it will highlight the same DOM element in HTML-View as before when the DOM-Element still exist.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Firstly, thank you. Perhaps I already have what I need the moment I edit the page. Can you check my clarification edit I just posted in the question? Secondly, When I push Firefox's reload button, my edited HTML changes disappear. So what exactly is http://getfirebug.com/html 's `Inspect, edit, reload` trying to show me?

Comment: For the 2nd part: They say that they highlight the same DOM-Element when you reload the page as highlighted before in Firebug's HTML-View. Example: Select the Facebook-Anchor-Tag on this SO-Page here. Then reload this page. Firebug's HTML-View will still highlight the Facebook-Anchor-Tag without the need selecting it again. That's all what they say about "reload" there.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, unless Firebug has some very nifty feature just for this purpose (by locally caching your changes and including them after the reload). I don't believe Firebug has this.

When you reload a new request/response happens and you get all your HTML + JS + CSS from the server. What you edit with Firebug is done locally.

Comment: So, what happens when I edit HTML code that affects JavaScript? Does Firebug "reload" that code on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

This button is a browser reload button, not from Firebug. That section says Firebug will keep an element selected in Firebug even if you reload the page. You can try using [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-se/firefox/addon/60/) to make changes and easily copy the code or [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/sv-SE/firefox/addon/748/) to write scripts to change the HTML dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

So you edited the `html` and `css`, you reloaded the Webpages, and your changes are gone? You definitely want to try my [LIVEditor](http://liveditor.com) that's just released, I developed because of this very same problem I faced when using Firebug to tweak css styles and html.

Comment: I am no longer working on such projects, but your solution sounds interesting. I'll let others explore it and take it from here. Thanks.

Comment: @MatthewDoucette, I'm glad you find LIVEditor's interesting :)